# neural network for data set with large number of samples

Tags: classification, neural-networks, sample, fitting, hyperparameter

What are the rules of thumb for neural network configurations with large number of samples? I have a dataset with 200k samples, 400 features, and binary label classification problem. How should I choose the hidden layer size? I'm concerned that during training the network will gradually forget the older samples, and will overfit over the samples fed to it recently. How can I make sure this doesn't happen, and the network nicely generalizes over entire data set? Particularly I'm interested in choosing the right number of hidden layers (probably 1 is enough), number of hidden nodes, minibatch size, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: How should I choose the hidden layer size?

See [Is there any method for choosing the number of layers and neurons?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/232393/12359)

> Q: I'm concerned that during training the network will gradually forget the older samples, and will overfit over the samples fed to it recently. How can I make sure this doesn't happen, and the network nicely generalizes over entire data set?

If that happens, make sure you randomly draw your batches, e.g. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijtrk.png):

> As for any stochastic gradient descent method (including
>   the mini-batch case), it is important for efficiency of the estimator that each example or minibatch
>   be sampled approximately independently. Because
>   random access to memory (or even worse, to
>   disk) is expensive, a good approximation, called incremental
>   gradient (Bertsekas, 2010), is to visit the
>   examples (or mini-batches) in a fixed order corresponding
>   to their order in memory or disk (repeating
>   the examples in the same order on a second epoch, if
>   we are not in the pure online case where each example
>   is visited only once). In this context, it is safer if
>   the examples or mini-batches are first put in a random
>   order (to make sure this is the case, it could
>   be useful to first shuffle the examples). Faster convergence
>   has been observed if the order in which the
>   mini-batches are visited is changed for each epoch,
>   which can be reasonably efficient if the training set
>   holds in computer memory.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijtrk.png) Bengio, Yoshua. "[Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533)" Neural Networks: Tricks of the Trade. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 437-478.

> Q:  I'm interested in choosing the right minibatch size

See  [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/12359)

---

You can compare the sequential vs. random access speed of your disk with CrystalDiskMark:

Crucial  512 GB m4 2.5-Inch Solid State Drive SATA 6Gb/s CT512M4SSD2:

[image]

Crucial M500 960GB SATA 2.5-Inch 7mm (with 9.5mm adapter/spacer) Internal Solid State Drive CT960M500SSD1:

[image]

A good explanation of the tests: http://www.overclock.net/t/1231707/can-someone-explain-the-different-crystaldiskmark-tests#post_17508715

> Sequential: Crystal disk mark (CDM) reads/writes whatever file size
>   you choose when you start the test sequentially. That is to say it
>   starts writing on a sector and then writes the next part on the
>   adjacent sector and so on. This is fastest because the head doesn't
>   have to move about a lot as all the sectors are adjacent.
>
> 512k: CDM read/writes to random sectors on the drive, but it
>   reads/writes 512KB of data at a random point, then moves to the next
>   random point. This is faster than 4k because there's more data
>   read/written with less movement of the head.
>
> 4k: The same as above but instead of reading/writing the test data in
>   512KB 'chunks' it reads/writes in 4KB chunks.
>
> 4kQD32: The same as 4K but there are more requests for the data sent
>   to the HDD controller. I'm told that some HDDs increase performance
>   when this happens because of the way their controller logic works but
>   I think this mostly applies to SSDs not mechanical drives.

Comment: Is the disk-reading concern relevant for systems which have SSD storage?

Comment: @Sycorax Not really I would tend to say unless maybe if you read a small batch from the disk at each iteration and your ANN is so fast that loading batches is significant: I have added some benchmarks in the answer. Also RAM is it cheaper nowadays :-)