# Online learning in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, lstm, online-algorithms

Recently, I have been working on RNNs (LSTM specifically) to do time series prediction and I have used different frameworks such as deeplearning4j and theano (keras). As you may know, one of the hyperparameters of the model is `batch_size` which has an effect on the model accuracy. I found [this paper](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/papers/Wilson.nn03.batch.pdf) which suggests that by using online learning instead of batch learning, the convergence can be reached significantly faster using on-line training than batch training, with no apparent difference in accuracy. Now I have the following questions:

1. How can we do online learning in any of those models? Does it basically mean to set the batch_size to 1?
2. Any ideas and thoughts about this? Is online learning really helpful?

It is worth to mention that I am trying to do time series analysis on streaming data and that is why I thought online learning might be useful in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we do online learning in any of those models? Does it basically mean to set the batch_size to 1?

yes

> Any ideas and thoughts about this? Is online learning really helpful?

see [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/12359)

Comment: It is a great question and I'm wondering what you think about the answer? Did you find that useful?