# Is there any other reason for using SGD than reducing time until convergence?

Tags: regression, stochastic-processes

Is there any other reason for using Stochastic Gradient Descent than reducing time until convergence? In other words, does it ever make sense to try out SGD when regular Gradient Descent runs fairly quickly?

Comment: In the case of neural networks, see [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/12359).

Comment: Incremental/online training is another reason.

Answer (score 2):

Memory (RAM) becomes a big issue if you are training with lots of data and that is another reason why SGD is preferred.

Comment: Overfitting can also be an issue, see answer of @FranckDernoncourt linked in his comment above.