# How does batch size affect Adam Optimizer?

Tags: conv-neural-network, adam

What impact does mini-batch size have on Adam Optimizer? Is there a recommended mini-batch size when training a (covolutional) neural network with Adam Optimizer?

From what I understood (I might be wrong), for small mini-batch sizes the results tend to be noisy, but the results are also innacurrate for big batches (let's say the whole training set in one pass).

Answer (score 10):

**Yes, batch size affects Adam optimizer**. Common batch sizes 16, 32, and 64 can be used. Results show that ***there is a sweet spot for batch size, where a model performs best.*** For example, on MNIST data, three different batch sizes gave different accuracy as shown in the table below:

```
|Batch Size | Test Accuracy        |
-----------------------------------|
|1024       |  96% with 30 epochs  |
|64         |  98% with 30 epochs  |
|2          |  99% with 30 epochs  |
|__________________________________|
```

Therefore, it can be concluded that decreasing batch size increases test accuracy. However, *do not generalize these findings, as it depends on the complexity of on hand data.*

[Here](https://medium.com/mini-distill/effect-of-batch-size-on-training-dynamics-21c14f7a716e) is a detailed blog ([Effect of batch size on training dynamics](https://medium.com/mini-distill/effect-of-batch-size-on-training-dynamics-21c14f7a716e)) that discusses impact of batch size.
In addition, following research paper throw detailed overview and analysis how batch size impacts model accuracy (generalization).

1. [Smith, Samuel L., et al. "Don't decay the learning rate, increase the batch size." arXiv preprint arXiv:1711.00489 (2017).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00489.pdf)
2. [Hoffer, Elad, Itay Hubara, and Daniel Soudry. "Train longer, generalize better: closing the generalization gap in large batch training of neural networks." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems. 2017.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08741.pdf)

Comment: +1 for a nice answer! Thanks for leaving the references, I would sure like to read those. Adding to this, decreasing batch size surely slow down model training, right?

Comment: Yes, compute time increases upon decreasing the batch size.

Answer (score 5):

I would just leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

There's an excellent discussion of the trade offs of large and small batch sizes [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network).