# Why is ReLU setting negative values to zero particularly?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I want to understand the logic behind keeping ReLU as $max(0,x)$ and not $min(0,x)$?

Why do we prefer positive inputs over the negative ones?

Comment: FYI sometimes it is preferable to use [leaky ReLUs](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222541/12359)

Comment: I don’t think it should matter to use maximum or minimum, since using minimum should be able to get the same outputs but with the weights flipped in signs. I am curious about setting the cutoff at zero, however. Using $\max\{1,x\}$ would mean that we could get the same output by changing the bias, but what consequences would there be for, e.g., numerical optimization or convergence speed.

Answer (score 6):

The weights learned in a neural network can be both positive and negative. So in effect, either form would work. Negating the input and output weights with the $\min$ form gives the same function as with the  $\max$ form. The max form is used purely by convention.

Comment: Can I keep it as $x$ only? Sparsity can anyway be induced by dropout. (PS Ignoring the non-linearity that $max$ or $min$ form would introduce in the system)

Comment: Without non-linearity, your network will compute just some linear function. No need to make it deep or anything.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question; why are we choosing activations functions that essentially kill negative values (this include ReLU/GeLU et al)?  Saying that we need non-linear activations functions isn't an answer, as there exist an infinite number of activation functions that are differentiable, etc.

Comment: You only 'kill negative values' if you have a bias term of zero and positive weights. More accurately, you limit the range of the input input on either side, at some value that can be learned through training.