# Why zero-centered output affected the backpropagation?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation

I read the answer in [Why are non zero-centered activation functions a problem in backpropagation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237169/why-are-non-zero-centered-activation-functions-a-problem-in-backpropagation/237282#237282?newreg=a5c5d7299a5e4adca8f9a7e6a69aa0cf) but I still can't understand.

Assume$$f=\sum w_ix_i+b$$ $$\sigma(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$, and loss function is $$L=\sigma(f)$$

To my understand, the gradient $$\dfrac{dL}{dw_i}=\dfrac{dL}{df}x_i=\dfrac{dL}{d\sigma}\dfrac{d\sigma}{df}x_i$$
So $\dfrac{dL}{dw_i}$ is actually depends on so-called *upstream gradient* $\dfrac{dL}{d\sigma}$, **since $\dfrac{d\sigma}{df}$ is always positive**.

So to my understand, I don't think non-zero-centred **output**($\sigma(x)$) activation function is a problem, the problem is non-zero-centred **derivative** ($\dfrac{d\sigma}{df}$) of activation function.

Is there anything wrong?

---

And what's the mathematical expression of *zero-centred*? Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effection is between two layers.

Consider a three-layer network:

$$X \Rightarrow h_1 = f(W_1X+b_1) \Rightarrow h_2 = f(W_2h_1+b_2) \Rightarrow L = W_3h_2+b_3$$

where $f(x)$ is sigmoid function.

When we optimize parameter $W_2$, no matter whether input $X$ is zero-centred or not, the input of this layer from the previous layer $h_1$ is always positive because sigmoid function is used in the previous layer as activation function, so $\frac{dL}{dW_{2,ij}}$ have the same sign and will cause a zig-zag path during optimization.

Comment: What about the first hidden layer? If we optimize with respect to $W_1$, values of $W_2$ affect the gradients $dL/dW_{1, ij}$. Since $W_{2, ij}$ values aren't restricted to be solely negative or positive, what guarantees the zig-zag problem with regards to the first layer?