# Why I think zero-centered activation function is no better than no zero-centered case? What's wrong with my understanding?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I read the answer in [Why are non zero-centered activation functions a problem in backpropagation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310771/why-zero-centered-output-affected-the-backpropagation)? I can understand that for a positive activation function, gradient of each dimension is of the same sign. but I still have a question:

for a zero centered data, we cannot have a gradient whose every dimension's component is of the same sign, so we still have some direction where we cannot go. Is it right?

For instance, the answer says

> Say there are two parameters $w1$ and $w2$, if the gradients of two
> dimensions are always of the same sign, it means we can only move
> roughly in the direction of northeast or southwest in the parameter
> space. This may leads to a zig-zag path if the optimal direction is
> northwest or southeast.

But if the data is zero-centered, the gradients of two dimensions are always of the different sign. Then we can only move in the direction of northwest or southeast, still leading to a zig-zag path if the optimal direction is northeast or southwest.

So in both cases we have some directions where we cannot go, leading to a zig-zag path.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with your understanding and I do agree with your point. In my opinion, there is a wide-spread misunderstanding on this. The explanation given [here](https://qr.ae/pN2N2J) seems quite reasonable. In other words, multiplication around zero tends to preserve range, which is desirable since every activation function is identical hence operates on a fixed range.