# Transfer Function on Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Do different Transfer Function produce different prediction in neural network model? How do we know which transfer function suitable for the data we used?

Answer (score 1):

> Do different Transfer Function produce different prediction in neural network model?

Most of the times, yes. It may matter a little or a lot, depending on the network, dataset, transfer functions, etc.

> How do we know which transfer function suitable for the data we used?

One way is to look at the transfer function existing models doing similar tasks use. Also: [Comprehensive list of activation functions in neural networks with pros/cons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/115258/12359)

Comment: Can you provide me a link or notes that can make me more understand regarding this matter.