# Requirements of a loss function for an NN

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

Which requirements has to accomplish a loss function?

Is differentiation the single requirement?

Comment: the loss function is closely related to the task to be solved. It is a broad topic. It is very well explained in Bishop's book "neural networks for pattern recognition"

Comment: below, two properties are called 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154879/a-list-of-cost-functions-used-in-neural-networks-alongside-applications